# Reading lines from a file using a try-catch block for exceptions C++

Tags: c++, validation, input, try-catch, inputstream

I want to read lines in certain length and parse them. To parse them I use exceptions to take care of specific bad inputs, but whenver I catch an error my buffer is filled with bad input and the next getline command puts gibberish in it even though there is still valid input in the file.

Here is my code:

(`inStream` is of type `istream` because if the file is invalid I read from `cin`)

```
char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
string line;
while (inStream.getline(buffer,MAX_LINE_LENGTH)) {
    line=string(buffer);

    try {
        parse(line, inStream, outStream);
    }

    catch(const DoneError& e){
        outStream<<e.what();
        return 0;
    }

    catch(const MyException& e) {
        outStream<<e.what();
    }

    //invalid_argument or out_of_range at stod & stoi
    catch (const logic_error& e)    {
        outStream<<BadParameterExeption().what();
    }

    catch(const exception& e){
        outStream<<e.what();
    }
}
```

After the first time I catch exception from `parse` (already in the catch block) `buffer` is filled with junk and not the original contents, also the next iteration of the loop fills `buffer` with junk and not the input.
I tried using `clear()` and `ignore(MAX_LINE_LENGTH, '\n')` after the catch blocks but it didn't help.
What can I do?
I want to read MAX_LINE_LENGTH chars at most so that if I get more than that in a single line I read it in the next iteration.

I read from a file (not redirecting), here's how:

```
ifstream  inpFile;
ofstream outFile;

/* I receive the files' names via argv, some are input some are output
 * (order is fixed but not the number)
 * /.prog outpu1 input1 output2 input2 (and so on)
 * degenerated example on how It works:
 *    for(int i=argc-1; i>0; i-=2){
 *       inpFile.open(argv[i]);
 *       if(inpFile.is_open()) return true;
 *    }
 */
if (!initFiles (argc, argv, inpFile, outFile))
    return 1;

istream &inStream = (inpFile.is_open()) ? inpFile : cin;
ostream &outStream = (outFile.is_open()) ? outFile : cout;
```

Comment: There is a `std::getline()` function, which operates on `istream`s and `string`s, use that instead of the memberfunction.

Comment: I know but as I said I need to read maximum of LINE_LEN chars every iteration even if the line contains more and `std::getline()` doesn't put a limit on how many chars it reads - it just reads the whole line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to supply more information.  The following works just fine when compiled with g++ 5.1.1 on Fedora.  Obviously, I had to create some of the missing infrastructure to get it to compile and run but I don't think I took too many liberties.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <exception>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define min(x, y) (x < y) ? x : y

const int MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 80;

struct DoneError : public exception
{
   const char *what() const throw()
   {
      return "Done Exception";
   }
};

struct MyException : public exception
{
   const char *what() const throw()
   {
      return "MyException";
   }
};

struct BadParameterExeption : public exception
{
   const char *what() const throw()
   {
      return "Bad Parameter";
   }
};

void parse(string l, istream &is, ostream &os)
{
   if (l.find("MyException") != string::npos)
      throw MyException();

   if (l.find("Done") != string::npos)
      throw DoneError();

   if (l.find("logic") != string::npos)
      throw logic_error("You made a logic error");

   if (l.find("BadParameter") != string::npos)
      throw BadParameterExeption();
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   ifstream inpFile(argv[1]);
   ofstream outFile(argv[2]);

   istream &inStream = (inpFile.is_open()) ? inpFile : cin;
   ostream &outStream = (outFile.is_open()) ? outFile : cout;

   char buffer[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
   string line;
   try {
      while (getline(inStream, line, '\n'))
      {
          while (line.length() > 0)
          {
             string smaller = line.substr(0, min(MAX_LINE_LENGTH, line.length()));
             line = line.substr(min(MAX_LINE_LENGTH, line.length()));
             try {
                 parse(smaller, inStream, outStream);
             }

          catch(const DoneError& e){
              outStream<<e.what()<<endl;;
              return 0;
          }

          catch(const MyException& e) {
              outStream<<e.what()<<endl;;
          }

    //invalid_argument or out_of_range at stod & stoi
          catch (const logic_error& e)    
          {
              outStream<<BadParameterExeption().what()<<endl;;
          }

          catch(const exception& e){
             outStream<<e.what()<<endl;;
          }
         }
      }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Since you're not really explained what you're ultimately trying to do you will probably have to refactor this in terms of processing the pieces of the input.  istream.getline() deals in raw characters and can be 'fiddly'

Comment: This is more or less what I do, I read a line and than throw an exception I made from my parse function (that has more local variables) and then read the next one.

I made a file with 2 lines: 

`bad command (should fail)`

`finish (should pass)`
.
`bad command` is read how it should, throws the right exception and prints what I need but when it reads finish the buffer has `)Zu`in it (gibberish varies from call to call) - gibberish. Why is that? Why is the next read fills my buffer with gibberish and not `finish`?

Comment: P.S I checked and already in the catch block buffer's content has changed to ` \030‘` or some other junk - it changes the moment it enter the catch block (I put a breakpoint on the signature and it was still fine but when I entered the block it changed). Could it be something with the `badbit` flag? Because using `clear()` or `ignore()` didn't help much.. BTW what more information do  I need to supply?

Comment: I open a file (not redirecting). Added partial code in original comment.

Comment: I do not observe the failures you report.  If the input file contains lines that are less than MAX_LINE_LENGTH then it appears the exception processing is working as expected (in the code I supplied).  If the input lines are longer than MAX_LINE_LENGTH then the stream has its failbit set and the loop is exited as expected.  See edited code (above)

Comment: I see.. So if I want the `line` to contain the same content as `buffer` (the `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` chars it manged to read) what should I do? And if the line is `x` times the length of `MAX_LINE_LENGTH`, what do I need to change so I could read it in `x` iterations?

Comment: You'll probably want to switch to <string> getline (see edits above) instead of the istream.getline just because of the characteristics of the two.